# How can I get the IP Address of a named Network Bridge in a batch file?

Tags: batch, windows-server-2003, network-adapter, bridge, bridging

I have a Network Bridge showing in my Network connections. How can I find out its IP Address in a batch script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this windows?

```
netsh interface ip show address "Network Bridge"
```

Replace the text in the quotes with the name of the bridge.